# Replacing a single character in string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace a single character in a large string *(textfile)* using C#.
this string contain multiple lines of code.

At some point a batch file is called assigning multiple parameters:

```
  call c:\script.bat 1 1 16 localhost 1 1 %0%
```

It must become:

```
  call c:\script.bat 2 1 16 localhost 1 1 %0%
```

I've created the following statement to replace the `regex` dot group *(in this case the first)*:

```
Regex.Replace(content, @"call c:\script.bat )(.)( 1 16 localhost 1 )(.)(%0%)","$1.$3$4$5")
```

Somehow I'm sure, replacing the `number 1` that is in place of the match can't be replaced with a `2` because then the replace string wil acces the non existing group `12` instead of `group 1` with the character `2` attached to it.

Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: Why must Regex be used? It's such overkill when `.Replace("1 1 16", "2 1 16")` is sufficient..

Comment: in a big file like I'm working with I have to be shure that only the string is adapted where this specific batchfile is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution would be to not capture the delimiting spaces:

```
Regex.Replace(content, @"(call c:\script.bat) \d (1 16 localhost 1 )(.)(%0%)","$1 2 $3$4$5")
```

**Note:** I've also used the `\d` digit character set. You may want to change this to `\d+` for numbers larger than a single digit.